# String in Python

Tags: python, list

Given this example:

```
string1 = 'Pythan' # String object
string1[4] = '0'
```

When attempting to modify index value 4, it results in an error, `'str' object does not support item assignment`.

A solution for this is to convert the string into a list first:

```
list1=list(string1)
print(string1)
```

**Output**

```
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'a', 'n']
```

Now changing the fourth element to 'o' works:

```
list1[4] = 'o'  #Now this modifies the 4th element.
print(list1)
```

**Question:**

If you select any particular element of the list and check its type (`type(list1[4])`) then it will return `'str'`. Why is it allowed to be modified, since the element is a string and strings are immutable?

Comment: Lists are mutable. You're not modifying a string, you're modifying a list, replacing a string.

Comment: You never modify a string, you only modify the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1[4] = 'o'
```

This statement creates a new string object and assigns it to the 5th element in `list1`.

To illustrate using the [`id()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#id):

```
def print_list(input_list):
    print(input_list)
    print([id(elem) for elem in input_list])

example_list = list("Pythan")
print_list(example_list)

example_list[4] = "o"
print_list(example_list)
```

**Output**

```
$ python3 test.py
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'a', 'n']
[140304019637840, 140304019089704, 140304019843648, 140304019687776, 140304019613992, 140304020050696]
['P', 'y', 't', 'h', 'o', 'n']
[140304019637840, 140304019089704, 140304019843648, 140304019687776, 140304019638120, 140304020050696]
```

Note how the memory addresses for all the elements are the same, except for the element which was replaced.

Comment: Thank you,  now I got the point that was reassignment, not performing any operation on that element.  Just to make sure I did following thing .  `list1[4][0]='o'` now this cause me `'str' object does not support item assignment`, which is obvious expected answer, because now this time trying to make change in string. Thank you again.I appreciate

Answer (score 1):

A list is just a sequence of references to other Python objects. In your example, the type of list1 will be list,

```
>>> type(list1)
<class 'list'>
```

so list1 is mutable. However, `list1[4]` refers to the immutable object `'a'`, so its type is str.

When you modify the list by `list1[4]='o'`, you actually just tell Python  to change the list by having its fourth element referencing to the immutable object 'o' instead of immutable object 'a', but both will reside as separate objects in memory and are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

in your code

for `str1 = 'python'`,here `str1` is a string object which is immutable.

now when you change the type of object say `list1 = list(str1)`, here list1 is of type list ie it's object type is list.

in str1 you can see any element at  particular position `str1[1] = 'y'` , strings are itreable, you cannt modified it as it is defined immuatable. but when you do same in a list object you can modify it  to any no or class object .

so see the coronology, str1 is of type string, where you can see the element at a position, and list1 is of type list where you can modify then element .

strings are immutable and iterable (you can access objects only read only) and list are mutable, iterable (can access and modify)